# Import module that was installed to environment after the program start

Tags: python, python-import

Let's say I have a virtual environment, my script has it activated, I run the script, it has an asynchronous background task to check if some new module was installed to the venv with `pkgutil.iter_modules`. After script run I install new lib to venv and background task detects it. I mean I don't want to restart the script after something new relevant was installed, but import it "on the fly".

Can it be done?

After some time spent on research (with reloading modules) I highly doubt about it, but maybe it is possible and I just did something wrong.

Comment: you could check the output of the background process and if it matches some value, import the new module in an `if` block.

Comment: It can be done, and fairly easily, but still sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you want to install during already existing runtime and not beforehand?

Comment: @wpercy I tried it with running coroutine in background that checks pkgutil.iter_modules every n seconds, but I did not work. I ran my program, than installed the lib and this background task didn't find it.

Comment: @wim I suppose it sounds like an antipattern, but it's pluggable async web server. And I would like to check let's say every minute if was installed some plugin for it, and if yes - load it and use it.